# How to round to 2 decimals in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a small program that calculates a percentage, but I can't find the way to round the result to 2 decimals.

- There is a field for inputting a number
- There is another field for inputting a second number (or increase it by clicking the button)
- There is a field that shows the percent

I believe I need to use something like `"{:.2f}"` in the function, but I don't know where exactly

This is the part of my code where I reckon I have to put the command:

```py
# Defining a function that takes any arguments and calulcates the proportion of the population and the vaccinated
def calculate(*args):
    try:
        popint = float(pop.get())
        vaccint = float(vacc.get())
        rate.set((vaccint / popint) * 100)
    except ValueError:
        pass  # Ignore for now

# Defining a function that increases by 1 the number of vaccinated
def addvacc(*args):
    try:
        vaccadd = int(vacc.get())
        vacc.set(vaccadd + 1)
        calculate()
    except ValueError:
        pass # Ignore for now

# Creating a window with title
root = Tk()
```

Everything is created already (buttons, labels, etc.), and it works.

[image]

I've attached the GUI of the program. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider sharing all your code

Comment: Use `rate.set("{:.2f}".format((vaccint / popint) * 100))`.

Comment: if you have Python 3.6+ and want to use `f strings` (which is kinda preferred): `rate.set(f'{(vaccint / popint) * 100: .2f}')`

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the percentage, and when you do this:

```
round(<your percentage value>,2)  #syntax: round(Value, digits to be rounded off to)
```

I just took an arbitrary float value and executed:

```
round(75.678780,2)
```

Output:
`75.68`